# When an 'enemy' hits a waypoint, all the enemies go to the next waypoint in the queue... Why?

Tags: c#-4.0

Here is the code I'm working on, I want all the enemies to go to each waypoint on their own accord; however, when one enemy hits the waypoint, all the enemies go to the next waypoint. How do I fix it?

I am running this from main, I have an enemy class and I have passed the queue in as a parameter when my enemy gets created. The original queue is called 'wayQ', the copied one that my enemies use is called 'way'.

Edit:
Here is the enemy class. I modified the code to overide the main update method.

```
class Enemy : GameObject
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public float scale = 0.3f;
    public Queue<Vector2> way = new Queue<Vector2>();
    private int atDestinationLimit = 1;

    public Enemy()
    {
    }

    public Enemy(ContentManager Content, int health, float speed, Vector2 vel, Vector2 pos, Queue<Vector2> wayQ)
    {
        this.Health = health;
        this.Speed = speed;
        this.velocity = vel;
        this.position = pos;
        this.IsAlive = true;
        this.texture = Content.Load <Texture2D>("SquareGuy");
        this.center = new Vector2(((this.texture.Width * this.scale) / 2), ((this.texture.Height * this.scale) / 2));
        this.centPos = this.position + this.center;
        this.way = wayQ;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
    {
        if (way.Count > 0)
        {
            if (Vector2.Distance(centPos, way.Peek()) < atDestinationLimit)
            {
                float distanceX = MathHelper.Distance(centPos.X, way.Peek().X);
                float distanceY = MathHelper.Distance(centPos.Y, way.Peek().Y);

                centPos = Vector2.Add(centPos, new Vector2(distanceX, distanceY));
                way.Dequeue();
            }
            else
            {
                Vector2 direction = -(centPos - way.Peek());
                direction.Normalize();
                velocity = Vector2.Multiply(direction, Speed);

                centPos += velocity;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Modify your `Enemy` class to have its own *copy* of the waypoint list. Creating a waypoint list and assigning it to each `Enemy` object gives each `Enemy` object a reference to one list. When you `Dequeue` a waypoint, you do so in the one list.

Comment: I've added the enemy class. Have I not created a copy?

Comment: No. The waypoint list is passed into your constructor by reference and doesn't get cloned. Good catch by Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda difficult to see without the code used by said enemies (which seem to contain the waypoint logic). Logic states that the waypoints for one enemy seem to be shared amongst all enemies - is the enemy.way field perhaps declared static?

Comment: No, I added the enemy class for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following code:

```
 this.way = wayQ;
```

to:

```
this.way = new Queue<Vector2>(wayQ);
```

Now it works great!